# Absolute continuity of discrete and finite measures

Tags: measure-theory

> Let $\mu, \nu$ be finite and discrete measures on some measurable space $(\Omega, \mathscr{A})$ where $\mathscr{A}$ contains all points. Give a necessary and a sufficient condition for $\nu \ll \mu$. Calculate all densities of $\nu$ with respect to $\mu$.

I am having trouble connecting some of the dots here. So since the measures are discrete and finite, there are $p_i > 0, \hat p_i > 0, \omega_i, \hat\omega_i$ such that $\mu = \sum_{i\in\mathbb{N}} p_i\delta_{\omega_i}, \nu = \sum_{i\in\mathbb{N}} \hat p_i\delta_{\hat\omega_i}$.

Now for the necessary condition assume $\nu \ll \mu$, therefore for all $A\in\mathscr{A}: \sum_{k\in\mathbb{N}} \hat p_k\delta_{\hat\omega_k}(A)=\nu(A)=\int_Afd\mu=\sum_{k\in\mathbb{N}} p_k\delta_{\omega_k}(A)f(\omega_k)$ for a Radon-Nikodým derivative $f$. Now letting $A=\{\hat\omega_i\}$ shows that we must have for all $i\in\mathbb{N}: \hat p_i = p_j f(\omega_j), \hat\omega_i = \omega_j$ for some $j\in\mathbb{N}$.
Therefore it is necessary (and clearly also sufficient) that $\{\hat\omega_i\}_{i\in\mathbb{N}}\subseteq\{\omega_i\}_{i\in\mathbb{N}}$.

Now assume without loss of generality that the sequence $\{\omega_i\}_{i\in\mathbb{N}}$ is ordered such that it begins with $\{\hat\omega_i\}_{i\in\mathbb{N}}$. Then the density of $\nu$ with respect to $\mu$ is given by $f(\omega)=\dfrac{\hat p_i}{p_i}$ if $\omega=\hat\omega_i$, $f(\omega)=0$ otherwise.

I am not sure what "other densities" I am supposed to compute here, since densities are unique $\mu$ almost everywhere.